# Count rows in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query that grabs a bunch of diffrent tables using LEFT JOIN, and I was wondering if I could incorporate another table, but only count the values in it.

**The problem**

When I try to use COUNT(row_id) in the query with everything else, it only returns the count and nothing anything else.

```
$query = "
    SELECT COUNT(subscriptions.sub_id) AS total_subscriptions, 
           postings.posting_id, 
           postings.posting_headline, 
           postings.posting_body, 
           postings.timestamp, 
           users.user_name 
    FROM postings 
    LEFT JOIN users ON postings.user_id = users.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN subscriptions ON postings.group_id = subscriptions.group_id 
    WHERE postings.group_id='" . $group['group_id'] . "' 
    ORDER BY postings.posting_id DESC
";
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Show the query please

Comment: Please show your query.

Comment: You will likely need to do a subquery to count rows from another table.

Comment: Probably not a subquery but a group-by.

Comment: Query added to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an explicit `GROUP BY` clause to the query.